# Consulta sobre FAB

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, floating-action-button

Tengo un aplicativo en proceso de construcción utilizando el `Navigation Drawer Activity` que es el que tiene el menú izquierdo como la vieja versión de `Google PlayStore:`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como sabrán el diseño viene incluído con un `FAB` `(FloatingActionButton)`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, en el menú lateral izquierdo vienes estos tres `Fragments`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisera saber, ¿Cómo le asigno distintas acciones al `FAB` cuando cambio el `Fragment`? Desde el `MainActivity` veo que está el k pero no entiendo como asignarle una funcionalidad distinta, ya que al cambiar de `Fragment`, el mismo `FAB` sigue estando y ejecuta la misma acción que en este caso es un `Toast`.

```
    binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Home Fragmen Visualizado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

La idea es, si alguien me puede explicar o decir como controlo la acción del `FAB` según el `Fragment` en el que esté.

Comment: Porqué no te vas por otra alternativa y creas un fab en cada fragment? Así tienes más control de cada fab. Lo que puedes hacer es primero encontrar qué fragment se está mostrando, a traves de un tag que le pones y según eso ver que haces en el onClickListener

Comment: Quería evitar hacer eso, si bien era una posibilidad quería evitar esa solución. Por lo cual, encontré otra que se adaptó a mi necesidad específica. @javdromero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que encontré, fue usar un `NavHostFragment` y asignarle el `Fragment` que utilizo, luego mediante la condición de IF he hecho lo de mostrar un `Toast` diferente según el `Fragment` en el que esté:

```
binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment); // cambiar `nav_host_fragment` según el que uses

        if (navHostFragment != null) {
            Fragment currentFragment = navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);

            if (currentFragment instanceof HomeFragment) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Home Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (currentFragment instanceof SlideshowFragment) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Slideshow Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (currentFragment instanceof GalleryFragment) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Gallery Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
});
```